# Read content from txt file to string including special characters

Tags: java, encode

I want to read text from a file and store it in a string . But I am unable to get the same content . I am using the below code

```
String content = readFile(filepath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
        throws IOException 
    {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }
```

My text file contains `Máquina blah blah` , `blah İletişim ve blah A.Ş.`
but When i am using UTF-8 encoding I am getting the output like this `M??quina blah blah` , 
`blah ??leti??im ve blah A.??.`

Please help me with the appropriate encoding feature to read my text as it is . Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes. I am using eclipse only

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, I've seen this issue before.
It's the output console which doesn't support characters you are trying to print. you need to ensure that your Eclipse install is configured to use UTF-8.

To do this,

*Window => Preferences => General => Workspace => Text File Encoding => set to UTF-8.*

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me .. Thanks :)

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileObj),"UTF-8"));
        String line = null;

        line = bufRdr.readLine();
          while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
            }
```